# Как обновить дату в столбце больше на 1 минуту?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Как обновить дату в столбце больше на 1 минуту?

Столбец `DATE_END` тип `DATE`

Из:

```
06.07.2021 10:06:54
```

нужно получить:

```
06.07.2021 10:07:54
```

Comment: Функцией DATEADD()

Comment: У меня так получилось, как пример:
select DATE_ADD('2018-05-25 21:25:54', INTERVAL 1 minute)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Просто добавте 1 минуту, больше ничего не нужно:

```
declare
    date_end date := to_date ('06.07.2021 10:06:54', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
begin 
     date_end := date_end + interval '1' minute;
     dbms_output.put_line ('result='||date_end); 
end;
/
```

Результат:

> result=06.07.2021 10:07:54

Следует учесть, в PL/SQL нет столбцов, только переменные. Столбцы есть в SQL, где тоже самое будет работать:

```
create table t (date_end) as
    select to_date ('06.07.2021 10:06:54', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from dual
/
update t set date_end = date_end + interval '1' minute;

1 row updated.

select * from t;

DATE_END
-------------------
06.07.2021 10:07:54
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE ТАБЛИЦА SET date_end= date_end + interval '1' minute WHERE УСЛОВИЕ
```

Comment: По видимому вы движки в вопросе перепутали. Какой вы имели в виду в вопросе?  PL/SQL, SQL или оба?

Comment: Имел ввиду PL/SQL

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ ещё раз,  я его дополнил.

Comment: _Имел ввиду PL/SQL_, пускай оба останутся - PL/SQL и SQL. Вы для себя только поймите разницу - SQL это язык запросов, а PL/SQL это язык программирования, который может вызывать SQL запросы. Если эта разница не совсем понятна, то просто задайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо, да мне нужно было преимущественно pl/sql. SQL также не помешает.