# Триггер прибавляющий на 5 сек больше фактического времени

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, триггер

Как написать триггер, который прибавляет 5 секунд к времени, когда заполняется столбец date_end таблицы PET?

Пример, до срабатывания триггера:

```
12.07.2021 14:35:20
```

После срабатывания триггера:

```
12.07.2021 14:35:25
```

Comment: Вы же задавали [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1302372). Какая разница - в триггере или вне его? Тем более непонятно, зачем тут триггер? А что такое - таблица PET?

Comment: В том вопросе был Update. В этом триггер который срабатывает в том случае когда идет заполнение поля date_end. А уже заполненное date_end не трогал. PET это таблица, в ней столбец date_end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделайте как в этом воспроизводимом примере:

```
create table t (date_end date)
/
create or replace trigger tinstrigg before insert on t for each row
begin 
    :new.date_end := :new.date_end + interval '5' second;
end;    
/
insert into t values (to_date ('12.07.2021 14:35:20', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
/
select * from t;

DATE_END
-------------------
12.07.2021 14:35:25
```

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ. Мне нужно только когда вставляется дата.

Comment: Посмотрите ваш вопрос, о чём вы там спрашиваете?

Comment: @wq55 _Посмотрите мой ответ_, в ответе вы просто добавили одну проверку на NULL. Её можно спокойно опустить, т.к. выражение с NULL вернёт в итоге NULL. Так что триггер в моём ответе будет также работать с вашим дополнительным требованием.

Comment: Т.е. нужно добавить одно условие после begin. :new.date_end := :new.date_end + interval '5' second; И у меня также можно if ... then убрать будет тоже самое.

Comment: @wq55 Да, это так, потому что NULL  + что-то всегда NULL.

Comment: Если нужно -5 сек. то поставить минус :new.date_end := :new.date_end - interval '5' second;

Comment: @wq55 Да. Вы же можете проверить, мой пример воспроизводимый, поставте минус и тут же увидете, что получится.

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace trigger tr_pet_date_end_2021
before insert on "PET"  
for each row
declare
 -- local variables here
begin
     if ( :new.date_end is not null)
     then 
     :new.date_end := :new.date_end + interval '5' second;
 end if;
end tr_pet_date_end_2021;
```